# How do you use reddit api voting feature?

Tags: python, api, module, target, reddit

Help I am stuck! Just writing python using reddit api wrapper when all of a sudden I learn that I do not know how to use the upvote/downvote feature. I just need to know how to target the post or comment. It is specified in item (see below) and I think it is declared in a variable.

```
item.upvote()
```

Answer (score 4):

`item` can be either a `submission` or a `comment`.

You can get individual submissions using [`r.get_submission`](https://github.com/mellort/reddit_api/blob/master/reddit/__init__.py#L692), or get top submissions from a subreddit with something like `r.get_subreddit('python').get_top(limit=10)`. A list of comments on a submission is at `submission.comments`

(Untested) example:

```
r = reddit.Reddit(user_agent='example')
r.login('username', 'password')
submission = r.get_submission('http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/92dd8/test_post_please_ignore/')
submission.upvote()
submission.comments[0].upvote()
```

Comment: This response should be the accepted answer. (I am the package maintainer.)